# A null StrongName was found in the full trust assembly list

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, strongname

I am trying to create a sandboxer that runs untrusted code. I have been following the example on the windows Docs linked here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox#example)

I have copied the example code into my Visual Studio solution to make the Sandboxer class and the Untrusted Class. On the Microsoft Docs it says this example should work and I can't find any more information about my problem

The example code is shown on the Microsoft Docs linked above, I have just copied the code in as instructed. The error is on this line...

```
        AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", null, adSetup, permSet, fullTrustAssembly);
```

the error states that 'A null StrongName was found in the full trust assembly list'
The StrongName is created on the following line of code...

```
    StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
```

Comment: Is the `trusted` assembly `signed`?  Step 2 in the docs clearly states `Sign the assembly that contains the hosting class (named Sandboxer in this example)`

Comment: How do I sign an assembly? I thought the line shown above signs the assembly but obviously not.